# Rooted, then flashed, now not able to root again /system is always read-only

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, unrooting

I rooted my Android ICS with some script.
It was rooted then I installed and removed some system application.
Then I formatted the device and re-installed the ICS.

Now when I try to root it again it gives error could not copy are you a root?
I searched for that and finally found that though I re-flashed it any times.
/system is read-only.
So then after I tried

```
adb shell
mount
```

then command of mount and it gives error permission denied.
Please help to reset the permission of /system so I can manually add the su file in it.

The technique i used to Root is at this [link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-viper-4g-lte/221448-ics-universal-root-xda.html).
Then i format using cwm and install new rom. Now i am not able to root it.

Comment: I would say that more information is probably needed. Like what device, how you rooted the device. you do not have permission to run "mount", unless you are root, to make /system not read-only, you have to have root. /system is read-only on purpose. there is nothing to fix there, it should be read-only.

Comment: What is the *some script* you are referring to?

Comment: i have added the link in question please check it.

Comment: "using cwm and install new rom". Are you sure the ROM you installed doesn't already have root? What ROM did you install?

Comment: Reinstalling ICS will revert the file you changed...

Comment: I reinstalled still not working the rom i am using is Refresh V2 from this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1788936)

Comment: @RyanConrad using cwm only i installed and the rom is not rooted

Comment: if you still have cwm you can file a flashable package that contains the su and SuperUser (or SuperSU) apps

Comment: how to do that?? any guide? now i am trying to flash with other rom then again will install refresh and then try to root it lets see whether it works or not

Comment: Now i'll go mad, from this [tutorial](http://iamrainwalker.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/symphony-w25-ktouch-w650-mobistar-s01-karbonn-a7-ics-upgrade-tutorial/) i installed ap it got installed then i installed cwm again and then installed new rom still getting error msg mount error are you root....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the question on same link shown in question. Till that i tried everything format SD card totally, also tried different roms of ICS still it was not worked.

Then as in reply i got on that forum saying install gingerbread rom then root it, use OTA root keeper and upgrade.

So i did similar to that i installed gingerbread.

Then i formatted all using cwm. Then i installed new ICS refrec v2 rom. And then after i tried to root it. And it worked.
Hope so if anyone face the same problem they can downgrade to GB then again move to ICS to root it after flash if their favorite rom doesn't come rooted. :)